# ImportError: cannot import name PyJavaClass

Tags: python, exception, module, jython

I check [my old script](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502222-creating-java-class-description-files/?in=user-4028109) written in 2007 in Python/Jython and it throw the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name PyJavaClass
```

What happen with this class, I use Xubuntu 13.4 with Jython 2.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PyJavaClass` was part of Jython 2.2: https://bitbucket.org/jython/jython/src/bed9f9de4ef3c6d38bc009409c95ebfc55e0c7d0/src/org/python/core?at=2.2.

It is gone in Jython 2.5. Now there is `PyJavaType` instead. See

- http://www.jython.org/javadoc/index.html
- https://bitbucket.org/jython/jython/commits/a173ad16080621b6d7a29fb764087758eb453ba1

I cannot find anything about this change in the release notes (http://www.jython.org/latest.html).